# Wordpress: custom content shows before $content

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I'd like to show some custom content after `the_content`. However, I can't make it work. the custom content always shows before `the_content`. Here's my code:

```
function after_content($content){



function custom_content() {


include('page.php');
...

 }


$content = $content . custom_content();
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'after_content');
```

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with all its workings but I have found using an output buffer helps put content in order.

Comment: try to return content from page.php and return from custom_content() function

Comment: i tried both, the output buffer and returning the content. the poblem seems to be the include('page.php'); if this is some other content: e.g. $myX = "test"
  return $myX; the custom_content appears after the $content. any suggestions how to include page.php? i tried $myX = include('quote.php'); return $myX; but then the custom_content appears before the $content